# GET request failed while using $.getJSON on facebook Graph Api

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

this is a a part of a PHP file.
its a facebook app hosted in Heroku.

The **GET request** is always failed although im using a valid access token.
(callback function never invoked).
What is wrong?

```
  <body>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
     {

    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=<?php echo $token; ?>&limit=4",
      function(json) {
       alert("JSON Data: " + json.data[0].id);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you access the URL directly (after copying it from your source code), do you get a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restriction of [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can't do this. Append `&callback=?`" to that URL

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=<?php echo $token; ?>&limit=4&callback=?",
```

Comment: tnx a lot! do you know if its better to use _javascript sdk_ or _curl_ functions?

Comment: @itamar: no it isn't. It's a lot easier with their SDK